# what is the "rails way" to throttle sending lots of messages to users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, throttling

When our rails 3 app sends messages (email or sms) to users we need ot throttle the rate at which we do so.

suppose

```
the_list = Messages.find(someconditions) 
the_list.each do |msg|
   msg.send_me
end
```

returns hundreds of messages, we (a) dont really want them all in memory at once and (b) cannot fire them off all at once.

If our practical limit is to send, say, 200 per minute, what is the rails way to 'find' them in smaller batches (b) throttle the calls to .send_me to meet our target send rate

FWIW we're running on Heroku and have delayed_job running now for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

To limit the amount of messages that are sent you can use this:

```
Messages.find(someconditions, :limit => 100)
```

If you want to throttle the easiest way is probably to create multiple delayed jobs where they are `run_at` a time in the future.

If you wanted to change your app a little further you could add a send_at time to your messages table, and when you create your messages do something like:

```
current_send_at = Message.for_user(current_user).latest.send_at || Time.now
new_message.send_at = current_send_at + 1.minute
new_message.save!
```

Then in your delayed job you'd select messages where `send_at < now()`. Does this make sense?

Comment: thank you! how do you then iterate through the next 100, the next 100 etc? wihtout re-finding the same 100 over and over?

Comment: Check my update, I think you're better off changing your model a bit.

Comment: delayed job does all that for us... we simply call msg.delay(xxx).send_me and it queues up the message for when we tell it. what I don't see from your example is how to iterate 100 messages at a time, not re-finding the same 100 message every time.

Comment: The problem is that doing it that way in delayed job means your jobs will potentially be quite long running. If you want to find in batches you can use the rails batched finders (http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/23/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-batched-find).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't offload this from the rails process there's no way to do it or you'll block the whole app. Start a micro instance on ec2 and poll a queue w/ messages to send. Offload it from rails.